# Installing snap package in encrypted home folder?

Tags: encryption, directory, home-directory, snap

After installing the snap of LibreOffice, it is not working in my Ubuntu 16.04LTS:

```
~$ /snap/bin/libreOffice failed to create user data directory. 

Error Message: Permission denied
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue and it has been fixed in the packages available from the xenial-proposed repo. If you just want the fix without enabling proposed, you can install the snap-confine and ubuntu-core-launcher from the repo, both are available at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap-confine/1.0.38-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 .

The bug is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592696